# eclipse: Project not built due to "Could not read file ... ~$somefile.xlsx"

Tags: java, eclipse, excel

I've got a excel file(somefile.xlsx) in my maven project.
A temp file `~$somefile.xlsx` would be generated automatically, if I modify this file. It also disappear automatically if I close the file.
With the existence of this temp file, eclipse failed to build my project. The problem window said:
`The project was not build due to "Could not read file :D:\myworkspace\src\main\java\com\mycompany\suites\~$somefile.xlsx".`

How to resolve this kind of problems? Should I try to tell eclipse or maven to ignore this temp file -- is there such a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to:

**Project > Properties > Resource -> Resource Filters -> Add**

Select:

- Exclude all
- Files
- All children (recursive)

Name matches:
~*

That should prevent eclipse picking up MS office tmp files.